# PERL key pair using cells of a csv file

Tags: perl

that is created from col0 and col3 of a csv file, i then do a sum of + 1 to the col3 key value.
 Next i want to change all the col0 cells to the hash key  associated with col3 value. How do i do that?
In essence if value of col3 changes col0 should be updated with its keypair.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arrayfruit;
my %fruits = ();
foreach (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $line     = $_;
    my @elements = split( ",", $line );
    my $fruit    = $elements[0];
    my $color    = $elements[1];
    my $type     = $elements[2];
    my $nmbr     = $elements[3];
    %fruits = ( $fruit => $nmbr );

    my $new_nmbr = $nmbr + 1;

    print "key number =  $nmbr  <--->  value fruit = $fruit \n"
      foreach ( keys %fruits );

    push @arrayfruit, "$fruit, $color  ,$type ,$new_nmbr \n";
}

__DATA__
APPLE,GREEN,FRUIT,1
TURNIP,WHITE,VEG,2
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
APPLE,GREEN,FRUIT,1
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,4
SPUD,BROWN,VEG,5
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,GREEN,FRUIT,4
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,4
SPUD,BROWN,VEG,5
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,4



Expected Data
TURNIP,GREEN,FRUIT,2
PLUM,WHITE,VEG,3
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
APPLE,GREEN,FRUIT,2
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,ORANGE,FRUIT,5
BLANK,BROWN,VEG,6
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,GREEN,FRUIT,5
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,ORANGE,FRUIT,5
blank,BROWN,VEG,6
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do what you're asking for. A hash isn't appropriate for relating integers to strings — you want an array for that. You also didn't explain what should happen when the new number doesn't correspond to any of the original values, so I've used `BLANK` which is what your own code does

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @fruits;

chomp(my @data = <DATA>);

for ( @data ) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    my ($fruit, $n) = @fields[0,3];
    $fruits[$n] = $fruit;
}

for ( @data ) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    $fields[0] = $fruits[++$fields[3]] // 'BLANK';
    print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
APPLE,GREEN,FRUIT,1
TURNIP,WHITE,VEG,2
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
APPLE,GREEN,FRUIT,1
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,4
SPUD,BROWN,VEG,5
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,GREEN,FRUIT,4
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,4
SPUD,BROWN,VEG,5
PLUM,RED,FRUIT,3
ORANGE,ORANGE,FRUIT,4
```

#### output

```
TURNIP,GREEN,FRUIT,2
PLUM,WHITE,VEG,3
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
TURNIP,GREEN,FRUIT,2
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,ORANGE,FRUIT,5
BLANK,BROWN,VEG,6
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,GREEN,FRUIT,5
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,ORANGE,FRUIT,5
BLANK,BROWN,VEG,6
ORANGE,RED,FRUIT,4
SPUD,ORANGE,FRUIT,5
```

Comment: @PerlDog: It has repercussions that I wasn't aware of. Also `use qw/ all FATAL /` simply doesn't work because of a bug in the pragma

Comment: @PerlDog: They were never right, it is just that no one noticed the problem